# the static files loaded many times in single request in node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem, I am trying to run a node.js server without any framework, I managed to make a function to run the server good and start handling the requests and also I managed to serve the static files correctly but the issue is the static files are loaded many times in the single request, so it confused me 
in the frontend, because javascript frontend executed many times, these are my functions

```js
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var url = require("url");
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var staticFolders = require("./config");
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port);


function SampleJs() {
    this.get = function (pass, cb) {
        server.on("request", function (request, response) {
            var getUrl = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
            var req = request;
            var res = response;
            res.render = function (pathFile, file, data) {
                if (pass == getUrl) {
                    var htmlSource = path.join(__dirname, pathFile, file);
                    fs.readFile(htmlSource, function (err, html) {
                        res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/html"});
                        res.write(html);
                        res.end();
                    });
                }
                if (req.url.match(/.css$/)) {
                    var cssSource = path.join(staticFolders.public, req.url);
                    var cssStream = fs.createReadStream(cssSource);
                    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/css"});
                    cssStream.pipe(res);
                }
                if (req.url.match(/.js$/)) {
                    var jsSource = path.join(staticFolders.public, req.url);
                    var jsStream = fs.createReadStream(jsSource);
                    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/js"});
                    jsStream.pipe(res);
                }
                if (req.url.match(/.jpg$/)) {
                    var jpgSource = path.join(staticFolders.public, req.url);
                    var jpgStream = fs.createReadStream(jpgSource);
                    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "image/jpg"});
                    jpgStream.pipe(res);
                }
                if (req.url.match(/.png$/)) {
                    var pngSource = path.join(staticFolders.public, req.url);
                    var pngStream = fs.createReadStream(pngSource);
                    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "image/png"});
                    pngStream.pipe(res);
                }
                if (req.url.match(/.jpeg$/)) {
                    var jpegSource = path.join(staticFolders.public, req.url);
                    var jpegStream = fs.createReadStream(jpegSource);
                    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "image/jpeg"});
                    jpegStream.pipe(res);
                }
                
                console.log(req.url);
            };
            cb(req, res);
        });
    }
}


var Handle = new SampleJs();

Handle.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("pages", "home.html", "hello");
});
Handle.get("/profile", function (req, res) {
    res.render("pages", "profile.html", "hello");
});
Handle.get("/manage", function (req, res) {
    res.render("pages", "manage.html", "hello");
});
```

the config file

```js
const path = require("path");
var staticFolders = {
    htmlView: path.join(__dirname, "pages/"),
    public: path.join(__dirname, "public")
};

module.exports = staticFolders;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. There is a bug. If `Handle.get` was called, `server.on('request')` will also be called. So in this case, `Handle.get` should not be called for over one time since this will register the duplicated `request` event.

```
function SampleJs() {
  var obj={};
  server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    var getUrl = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    if (getUrl in obj) {
      res.render = function (pathFile, file, data) {
        if (getUrl in obj) {
          // ...
        } if (req.url.match(/.css$/)) {
          // ...
        } if (req.url.match(/.js$/)) {
          // ...
        } if (req.url.match(/.jpg$/)) {
          // ...
        } if (req.url.match(/.png$/)) {
          // ...
        } if (req.url.match(/.jpeg$/)) {
          // ...
        } console.log(req.url);};
      obj[getUrl](req, res);
    }
  });
  this.get=function(pass, cb) {obj[pass]=cb;}
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the req and res objects is undefined

Comment: good but the function doesn't work correctly, the html file load successfully but the static file such as js, css, images, don't loaded